# Java String Parameter memory

Tags: java

for this method

```
public void testMethod( String paramString)
{
 String copyString = paramString;
}
```

does copyString create a new copy in memory of paramString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `paramString` is a variable of a reference type, `String` to be exact. `paramString` holds the value of a reference to a `String` object. When you do

```
String copyString = paramString;
```

you are copying the value of that reference and assigning that copy to a second variable, `copyString`. You aren't copying an object, you are copying the value of a reference.

Answer (score 2):

No, you provide a reference to the same object.

The most important part here is that Strings are immutable. Even though these two objects have a reference to the same object, they will not affect eachother once the reference has been assigned.

Since strings are immutable, changing the value of the string in one reference will simply create a new string and make the reference point to the new one. The old reference will remain untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the other answers state, you're making `copyString` *point* to `paramString`.

If you want to produce a ***copy*** of `paramString` you should perform this assignment:

```
String copyString = ((String)paramString.clone());
```

`clone()` is an Object's method, that means every object from any class will have it, and returns a new instance of an object with another reference, or simple, a copy. As it returns an object, you must do the proper casting.